# как присвоить переменной разные значения?

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли присвоить переменной разные значения в зависимости от года, согласно этой таблице?

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>разница дней равна</td>
    <td>если год ≥ и ≤</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>300-399 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>400-499 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>500-599 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>600-699 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>700-799 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>800-899 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>900-999 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>1000-1099 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1100-1199 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1200-1299 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>1300-1399 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>1400-1499 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>1500-1599 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>10</td>
    <td>1600-1699 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>1700-1799 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>1800-1899 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>1900-1999 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>13</td>
    <td>2000-2099 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>2100-2199 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>2200-2299 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>2300-2399 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>16</td>
    <td>2400-2499 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>2500-2599 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>2600-2699 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>2700-2799 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>19</td>
    <td>2800-2899 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2900-2999 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>3000-3099 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>3100-3199 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>22</td>
    <td>3200-3299 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>3300-3399 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>3400-3499 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>3500-3599 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>25</td>
    <td>3600-3699 г. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>3700-3799 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>3800-3899 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>3900-3999 г.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: #00f;">
    <td>28</td>
    <td>4000-4099 г. </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Или может быть возможно как-то рассчитать эти значения, если год кратный **100** делится на **400** без остатка то значение не изменяется, если делится с остатком то увеличивается на единицу ***`другими словами переменной надо присвоить значение равное разнице дней между юлианским и григорианским календарями`***

Comment: Формула для разница дней между календарями легко ищется, да и выводится элементарно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто перевести таблицу в JS можно так:

```js
let data = [];

$('tr').each(function(irow) {
  let row = [];
  $(this).find('td').each(function(icol) {
    row.push($(this).text());
  });
  let obj = {}
  obj.days = parseInt(row[0]);
  if (isNaN(obj.days)) {
    return;
  }
  obj.since = parseInt(row[1].match(/([0-9]+)-/)[1]);
  obj.till = parseInt(row[1].match(/([0-9]+)-/)[1]);
  data.push(obj);
});

console.log(data);
```

В итоге получается список объектов такого вида:

`{days: 1, since: 400, till: 499}`

---

Для удобного извлечения данные можно сохранять в словарь:

```
let data = {};

$('tr').each(function(irow) {
  let row = [];
  $(this).find('td').each(function(icol) {
    row.push($(this).text());
  });
  let obj = {}
  obj.days = parseInt(row[0]);
  if (isNaN(obj.days)) {
    return;
  }
  obj.since = parseInt(row[1].match(/([0-9]+)-/)[1]);
  obj.till = parseInt(row[1].match(/-([0-9]+)/)[1]);
  data[obj.since] = obj;
});

function getDif(year) {
  year = Math.floor(year / 100) * 100;
  let obj = data[year];
  if (obj)
    return obj.days;
  else
    return null;
}

// Даёт 4
console.log(getDif(899));
// Даёт null
console.log(getDif(3));
```

---

Немного теории (которой, как можно предположить из вопроса, не хватает). Здесь я использовал популярную библиотеку [jQuery](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) для удобной обработки HTML. Переменной здесь не нужно присваивать разные значения (что спрашивается в вопросе), так прошлые данные будут теряться. Полезнее использовать несколько переменных либо [структуры данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) вроде [массивов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))/[списков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) и [словарей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) (что в коде и показано).

Comment: Мне нужно просто присвоить переменной соответствующие значения, например var raznica = 1 если год больше или равно 300 и меньше или равно 499, как это реализовать на js?

Comment: Именно это я и реализовал в JS внутри функции `getDif`. У вас, кажется, большие пробелы в элементарных знаниях, если готовый, работающий код не воспринимается. Но это уже не сюда, а в учебники идти надо.

Comment: Да не спорю, мои знания в этой области чуть более нуля, в процессе выполнения скрипта я получаю три и более дат, часть из которых по григорианскому календарю, а часть по юлианскому, моих знаний хватит чтобы добавить к дате дни, и не было бы проблем если количество дней было фиксированным, но как добавить разное количество дней в зависимости от года я не знаю...

Comment: @blondinka в коде выше я реализовал парсинг данных из таблицы и функцию, которая получает год в качестве аргумента и на основе тех данных возвращает разницу в днях. Но это исходя из оригинального вопроса про таблицу, как уже было сказано в комментарии от Alexey Ten, задачу можно решить и без парсинга таблицы, но это уже не исходно заданный вопрос (а на этом сайте отвечают именно на конкретные вопросы).

Comment: @blondinka Советую всё же разобраться с основами JS, реализовать алгоритм перевода дат между календарями без обработки таблиц, это даже ещё проще. А здесь ваши задачи за вас не решают, только помогают с отдельными, не самыми тривиальными моментами.